# Issue using Task.WaitAll() for services in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I have a service with following OnStart() method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  this.manager.StartManager();
  this.log.LogEvent(this.id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Service started"));
}
```

and OnStop() method:

```
protected override void OnStop()
{      
  this.manager.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();      
  this.log.LogEvent(this.id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Service stopped"));
}
```

StartManager() method is implemented as following:

```
public void StartManager()
{
    foreach (var reportGeneratorThread in this.ReportGenerators)
    {                
        reportGeneratorThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    try
    { 
        Task.WaitAll(this.Tasks.ToArray());
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
            {
                var taskException = v as TaskCanceledException;
                if (v != taskException)
                {
                    foreach (var reportGenerator in this.ReportGenerators)
                    {
                        if (reportGenerator.Task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            this.logger.LogEvent(this.Id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Unhandled exception from Task " + reportGenerator.Task.Id));                             
                            ReportGeneratorThread faultedReportGeneratorThread = this.GetThreadById(reportGenerator.Task.Id);
                            var index = this.ReportGenerators.FindIndex(t => t.Equals(faultedReportGeneratorThread));
                            this.DisposeFaultedThread(faultedReportGeneratorThread, index);                           
                            this.ReportGenerators[index].Start();    
                            this.logger.LogDebug(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Faulted Task, and instance of ReportGeneratorThread is recreated and corresponding task is started"));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (taskException != null)
                {
                    this.logger.LogEvent(this.Id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Task " + taskException.Task.Id + " has thrown a Task Canceled Exception"));
                }
            }
    }
}
```

The issue occurs in my StartManager() method, since the reportGeneratorThread.Start() method is starting a task which continuously generates a report in a while loop, which can only be aborted once a cancellation token is thrown and I'm throwing it in my service OnStop() method.
So when I'm testing my service, the program cannot reach further than the Task.WaitAll(), which prevents me to complete the OnStart() method, and I'm receiving following error:

```
 Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
```

I still need to manage my task, so I actually need the Task.WaitAll() method, but I need to fix this issue as well. How do I complete the OnStart() method in this case ?. What is the best approach without changing the structure of my code.

Adding more parts of my code:

This is the method which is invoked by my task:

```
 private void DoWork()
    {
        while (this.Running)
        {
            this.GenerateReport();
            Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.DefaultSleepDelay);
        }

        this.log.LogDebug(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Worker thread stopping."));
    }
```

and the GenerateReport() method: I calling the Stop() method if cancellation is requested by the service. This method throws a TaskCancelledException.

```
 public void GenerateReport()
    {
        if (this.cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            this.Stop();
        }

        var didwork = false;
        try
        {
            didwork = this.reportGenerator.GenerateReport(this.getPermission, this.TaskId);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.log.LogError(ReportGenerator.CorrelationIdForPickingReport, string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Error during report generation."), 0, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!didwork)
            {
               Thread.Sleep(Settings.Default.ReportGenerationInterval);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need `Task.WaitAll`.

Comment: Please explain more why you think you need `WaitAll()`, I don't see you doing anything except handing errors which could be done inside the method `reportGeneratorThread` is running.

Comment: Where do you ever check for cancellation? Do you assume that calling `.Cancel()` throws an exception in the task?

Comment: I just didn't include my code in AggregateException before in order to avoid confusedness, but I have updated it now. I need to use Task.WaitAll() method in order to restart a faulted thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clearly illustrate your question, it's hard to understand exactly what the code is doing. There are at least a few oddities I see right off the bat:

1. Your method purports to restart a report-generator thread. But as near as I can tell, it can only restart *one*. If you have any more faults later on, there's no code waiting to detect that and handle it.
2. Using `WaitAll()` will prevent the code from detecting even one faulted, until *all* of the tasks have completed. So they either all need to fault before any get restarted, or you won't detect the fault until you're actually stopping the service and cancelling the tasks.
3. The only time `v != taskException` will be true is if `taskException` is `null`. So it seems to me that checking that it's non-null later is pointless.
4. I don't see the point in sleeping for 1 second between starting each task.

So I'm not sure it's possible to know what the best way to fix all this code is. That said, it seems that the immediate problem is clear: your `OnStart()` method is required, by design, to return in a timely manner, but your current implementation fails to do that. This basic issue seems solvable, by making the `StartManager()` method an `async` method and using `await` to return control to the caller until something interesting happens. That might look something like this:

```
public async Task StartManager()
{
    foreach (var reportGeneratorThread in this.ReportGenerators)
    {                
        reportGeneratorThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    try
    { 
        await Task.WhenAll(this.Tasks.ToArray());
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        foreach (var v in e.InnerExceptions)
            {
                var taskException = v as TaskCanceledException;
                if (v != taskException)
                {
                    foreach (var reportGenerator in this.ReportGenerators)
                    {
                        if (reportGenerator.Task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            this.logger.LogEvent(this.Id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Unhandled exception from Task " + reportGenerator.Task.Id));                             
                            ReportGeneratorThread faultedReportGeneratorThread = this.GetThreadById(reportGenerator.Task.Id);
                            var index = this.ReportGenerators.FindIndex(t => t.Equals(faultedReportGeneratorThread));
                            this.DisposeFaultedThread(faultedReportGeneratorThread, index);                           
                            this.ReportGenerators[index].Start();    
                            this.logger.LogDebug(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Faulted Task, and instance of ReportGeneratorThread is recreated and corresponding task is started"));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (taskException != null)
                {
                    this.logger.LogEvent(this.Id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Task " + taskException.Task.Id + " has thrown a Task Canceled Exception"));
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from `OnStart()` like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  // Save the returned Task in a local, just as a hack
  // to suppress the compiler warning about not awaiting the call.
  // Alternatively, store the Task object somewhere and actually
  // do something useful with it.
  var _ = this.manager.StartManager();
  this.log.LogEvent(this.id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Service started"));
}
```

Note that the proposed changes above do nothing to address any of the oddities I mentioned. It seems to me that a more useful implementation of the method might look something like this:

```
public async Task StartManager()
{
    foreach (var reportGeneratorThread in this.ReportGenerators)
    {                
        reportGeneratorThread.Start();
    }

    while (true)
    {
        try
        { 
            Task task = await Task.WhenAny(this.Tasks.ToArray());

            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // Unpack the exception. Alternatively, you could just retrieve the
                // AggregateException directly from task.Exception and process it
                // exactly as in the original code (i.e. enumerate the
                // AggregateException.InnerExceptions collection). Note that in
                // that case, you will see only a single exception in the
                // InnerExceptions collection. To detect exceptions in additional
                // tasks, you would need to await them as well. Fortunately,
                // this will happen each time you loop back and call Task.WhenAny()
                // again, since all the tasks are in the Tasks collection being
                // passed to WhenAny().

                await task;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception v)
        {
            var taskException = v as TaskCanceledException;
            if (v != taskException)
            {
                foreach (var reportGenerator in this.ReportGenerators)
                {
                    if (reportGenerator.Task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        this.logger.LogEvent(this.Id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Unhandled exception from Task " + reportGenerator.Task.Id));                             
                        ReportGeneratorThread faultedReportGeneratorThread = this.GetThreadById(reportGenerator.Task.Id);
                        var index = this.ReportGenerators.FindIndex(t => t.Equals(faultedReportGeneratorThread));
                        this.DisposeFaultedThread(faultedReportGeneratorThread, index);                           
                        this.ReportGenerators[index].Start();    
                        this.logger.LogDebug(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Faulted Task, and instance of ReportGeneratorThread is recreated and corresponding task is started"));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.logger.LogEvent(this.Id.ToString(), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "System"), string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Task " + taskException.Task.Id + " has thrown a Task Canceled Exception"));

                // Cancelling tasks...time to exit
                return;
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The above will loop, immediately restarting faulted tasks as they occur, but exit completely if one is cancelled.

**NOTE:** lacking a good code example to start with, the above is browser-code: completely uncompiled, untested. I don't recall off the top of my head the specifics of how exceptions are propagated from `WhenAll()` and `WhenAny()`…I think I got the examples right, but it's entirely possible you'll need to adjust the specifics for it to work. I hope that at least the basic idea is expressed in a useful way.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can I ask why you're not using an AggregateException in your proposal ?

Comment: @OsmanEsen: only in the second example. And like I noted, while I just can't remember for sure how exceptions are reported from `WhenAny()`, my recollection is that `WhenAny()` just rethrows a single unpacked exception, not an `AggregateException` as `WhenAll()` does. I still haven't bothered to test this today, but [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to confirm my assumption.

Comment: I have implemented the proposal, But I cannot even catch a general Exception using Task.WhenAny ()

Comment: @OsmanEsen: sorry, my mistake. I forgot that `WhenAny()` returns the task that completed. You need to either then await _that_ `Task` object (which would then throw the exception), or you need to check the object's status explicitly, and retrieve any exception from the `Task.Exception` property. I will update the code example to illustrate.

Comment: Thank you veru much. Will this solution cause a deadlock (async await) ?.

Comment: @OsmanEsen: there's not any risk of deadlock in the code I posted. But I just copy/pasted some of the code from your original example; without the full context, it's impossible to know for sure whether your full code might have such a possibility. Deadlock occurs when you have two or more synchronization objects (locks) and they are not always acquired in the same order. If you are careful to avoid that in your full implementation, then there won't be any deadlock.